# Compare two queries in PHP-MySQL based on datetime and insert selected data into a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have `Table1` and `Table2` in a MySQL database. I want to select `animals` and `gardens` data from `Table1`, then I would like to select `new_animals` and `new_gardens` from `Table2` which datetime is within the last week. Then, while calling the `mysql_fetch_array ($row1)` data from `Table1`, if both of `animals` and `gardens` fields are not previously recorded in `Table2`, insert `date`, `animals` and `gardens` into `new_date`, `new_animals` and `new_gardens` in `Table2`.

Please take a look at the schematic picture of tables and review the code in below. Note that `Table1` returns 4 rows from `$select_query1`, and since data is not recorded in `Table2`; it should be inserted into the `Table2`. The below code works fine without the if condition, but not working with the if condition. Could you please let me know your corrected version of the if condition in this problem?

```
$select_query1 = mysql_query("SELECT date, animals, gardens FROM Table1");
$select_query2 = mysql_query("SELECT new_animals, new_gardens FROM Table2  
                                          WHERE new_date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now()");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($select_query1); // This returns 4 rows
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($select_query2); // This returs 4 rows
    while ($row1) {
        if ($row2['new_animals'] !== $row1['animals'] && $row2['new_gardens'] !== $row1['gardens']) {
            $animals = $row1['animals'];
            $gardens = $row1['gardens'];
            $date = $row1['date'];
            $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table2 (new_date, new_animals, new_gardens) 
            VALUES ('$date', '$animals', '$gardens')");
    }
}
```

[image: schematic picture of tables]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statement is incorrect. You compare rows  from table1 with only the first row from table2 . What you  have to do is compare the the  rows from table1 with all the rows of table2.

Try this

```
$select_query1 = mysql_query("SELECT date, animals, gardens FROM Table1");

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($select_query1)) {

    $select_query2 = mysql_query("SELECT new_animals, new_gardens FROM Table2WHERE new_date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now()");
    $count=0;
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($select_query2))    
    {
        if ($row2['new_animals'] == $row1['animals'] && $row2['new_gardens'] == $row1['gardens']) {$count=1;}
    }

    if($count==0)
    {
        $animals = $row1['animals'];
        $gardens = $row1['gardens'];
        $date = $row1['date'];
        $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table2 (new_date, new_animals, new_gardens)
        VALUES ('$date', '$animals', '$gardens')");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show what you get from the second query. add this to your while loop var_dump($row2);

Comment: Oke does it show 4 times the same and if so did you put the var_dump in the second while loop or the first. You should put it in the second.

Comment: yes it was in second, I will add the example tables into my database and send you the result again,

Comment: That means that your query is flawed. check your query for mistakes.

Comment: iCode4U, awesome, thanks a lot, found my mistake, thanks again for your time and help, cheers

Comment: no problem, but all of the rows you get are the same and thats the problem you should first check if the query works properly by testing it in your database so not with php. Then jus go step by step through your code and check where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $select_query1 = mysql_query("SELECT date, animals, gardens FROM Table1");
  $select_query2 = mysql_query("SELECT new_animals, new_gardens FROM Table2  
                                      WHERE new_date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now()");

$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($select_query1); // This returns 4 rows
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($select_query2); // This returs 4 rows

$animalsArray = array();
   while ($row2) {
  $animalsArray[ $row2['new_animals']."_".$row2['new_gardens'] ]=$row2["new_animals"];
   }

$insertValues = "";
while($row1){
   if( $animalsArray[ $row1['animals']."_".$row1['gardens'] ] == "" ){
        $animals = $row1['animals'];
        $gardens = $row1['gardens'];
        $date = $row1['date'];
      $insertValues .= "('$date', '$animals', '$gardens'),";
   }
}

$insertValues = substring( insertValues,0,-1); //delete last comma
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO Table2 (new_date, new_animals, new_gardens)VALUES ".$insertValues." ;
 mysql_query($insert_query);
```

this line
      `$animalsArray[ $row2['new_animals']."_".$row2['new_gardens'] ] =         $row2["new_animals"];`

Create a position en array like that = $animalsArray[donkey_alabama] = 'donkey';

and this line
      `if( $animalsArray[ $row1['animals']."_".$row1['gardens'] ] == "" ) {}` 
Validate if exist that animal and garden , if not then  insert

insertValues is to insert all values in one statement ( faster)

PD: Use mysqli_

Comment: thanks a lot for your solution. Still I am trying to integrate your solution with my codes and will let you know if successful,